# How can I add TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.1 to ssl protocols?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I use the DigitalOcean server for my project. The server's default tls is TLSv1.3

But on my Nginx configuration, even if I don't add `TLSv1.3`, still only `TLSv1.3` appears.

How can I add `TLSv1.2` to SSL protocols?

The problem is, if I use `TLSv1.3`, there is a `handshake tls version` error on `Flutter`, So I need to add old versions.

`nginx` and `openssl` version:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
```

`nginx` configuration:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```

You can check tls version on this link:
[tls version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EplJf.png)

Output of `nginx -t`

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Could you temporarily for troubleshooting disable the ssl_ciphers directive and check if this changes anything. Was the default config tls1.3 only?

Comment: @LukasRäpple I commented ssl_ciphers lines.  Nothing has changed.

Comment: Sorry, @MichaelHampton. The output is too long because I have many addon domains and subdomains. I saved it as a text file. You can find on this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kv36bgakec48zd/nginx%20-T.txt?dl=0

Comment: Now you can see that these directives are defined in two different places: in your own configuration, and in the letsencrypt configuration file provided by certbot.

Comment: I updated /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf file. Please check the updated output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r49s20ms8th8pp8/nginx.txt?dl=0. But again TLSv1.2 doesn't appear. Please, help me

Comment: Have you tried to apply Mozilla recommendations? "moz://a SSL Configuration Generator" at https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ can be useful as a template tuned pretty nice, as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

nginx seems to first select TLS version and only after that check the SNI.

Therefore, it selects `ssl_protocols` using the same algorithm as is used to select default virtual host. That is, if there is a `server` block with `listen ... default_server`, `ssl_protocols` is used from that block. Otherwise first `server` block `ssl_protocols` is used.

This means that you need to specify all virtual host `ssl_protocols` at the `http` level and include all protocols any virtual host needs.

You can read more in [nginx mailing list message](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2014-November/045733.html)